# What is the name of this faucet brand?

Tags: plumbing, faucet

It's a pull out kitchen faucet with a swirly e logo.  I need to replace the hose.

[image: swirly e logo]

Comment: Which hose? The supply hose from the shutoff valve or the one in the pullout faucet? Supply hoses are standard. If the pullout take it out and go to a plumbing supply. They can probably fix you up.

Comment: The one in the pullout part.  We got a referral for a local plumbing supply, will hit them up tomorrow.

Answer (score 3):

That's the logo of Eclipse Stainless Faucets, https://mycountertopshoppe.com/products-services/accessories/faucets/64-eclipse-stainless-faucets

[image]

Comment: Great answer, thanks and welcome to Home Improvement!